# Bypassing the unique constraint when defining a foreign key to just one field in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I've a model as shown below:

```
class Instance(models.Model):
    data_version = models.IntegerField(default=1, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

The data_version field has to be related to all other models in the application:

```
class Source(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    version = models.ForeignKey(Instance, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='data_version', null=True)
```

The problem here is that Django requires the field `data_version` to be a unique field for me to be able to define such a relationship but that simply doesn't fit into my use case. I need to have multiple Instance objects in the app, each with version numbers starting from 1.
What I'd like is to have a unique constraint on the combination of `name` and `data_version` but then Django doesn't allow defining Foreign key relationships as shown above. Is there a way I can bypass this restriction?

Comment: Why are you defining `to_field` in the `version` field? If the ForeignKey points to the `pk` of the `Instance` model, it should be OK. Does that cover your use case?

Comment: It doesn't. The foreign key has to be to just to the `data_version` field.